Get HTML file from asset folder Angular 15
I have an angular 15 application wherein I am fetching HTML files in the component which is stored in the Asset folder as below:
this.httpClient.get('/assets/DPFiles/myfile1.html',{responseType:text}).subscribe(data=>.......
This works well my locally, However, it is not working on post-deployment to the Ubuntu server. when an API call is made from UI it gives 404.
What I have done is, in angular.json as below:
assets:[
'src/favicon.ico',
'src/assets'
],

in base href file of output is base href="./"
I also tried giving the path as "./assets/...' in API call with no luck.
also, read-write access is to that folder and file on Ubuntu.
what could be a missing thing here? why does it work locally and not on the Dev server also DPFiles folder I created recently
